# "Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions" error

Tags: opengl, windows, installation

[image: blender error message]

Is there a chance of fixing this? (the autodesk maya was working fine and I want to try this program, could someone help me with this?)

Comment: What kind of graphics card are you using?

Comment: Have you tried the "regular" version of Blender? Steam does nasty things sometimes, so I'd suggest you try to download the zipped version from blender.org, extract that to your desktop and post the results.

Comment: See if the answers in [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/451/what-version-of-opengl-does-blender-use?rq=1) question help at all.

Comment: I did try to download it again and it didn't work... My graphics card is "AMD Radeon (TM) HD 7450A Graphics"

Answer (score 1):

I reported this as a bug (I actually asked the same question [Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between different OpenGL versions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51653/warning-legacy-wgl-is-unable-to-select-between-different-opengl-versions)) and this is what the blender developer site said:

"Your GPU is too old. You may be able to still use it if you update your drivers."

The bug report is available [here](https://developer.blender.org/T48353).

Comment: To update your drivers, go to the AMD website and search for the drivers.