# Can I create an OpenGL 1.1 game on Blender 2.78 32-bit Game Engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, opengl

Not Just OpenGl ES 1.1, is there a way to limit which OpenGL ES Blender will use, a warning of what the game is going to require or disable certain features so if a game Required OpenGL 2.0, with in-game settings can be Lowered to Require OpenGl 1.1 (Disabling Material or Converting Material to UVmaps to Texture when compiling game)

Cause I just wiki'd Opengl ES thinking to see OpenGl ES 1.1 & 1.0 for JarPhones, but saw 

 - Nintendo 3DS under OpenGL ES 1.1 (In Which RE:Revelation 3DS is on)

 - while my 2012 phone is OpenGl ES 2.1 (SGH-T699, Adreno 225, can't play PS2 emulator called Play!)

 - PS2 has OpenGL ES 3 which my 2005 Dell D800 (Nvidia Go5650) Laptop could run PS2 emulators and so can the LG F3Q (2014, OpenGL ES 3, Adreno 305) which means Mobile is approx 6 years behind PC technology

 - OpenGL ES 3.x is on Adreno 300, 400 & 500 Series for Mobile

 - PS3 & PS4 might be 3.x - 4.x

 - My 2014 Laptop now has OpenGL 4.5

Kivy is multiple platform (Though having trouble with Android) as it uses Python (Cython) and Blender & Panda3D are the only 2 left with OpenGL & Python as pyOpenGL is broken.

I need to know cause I want to create a game that can possibly be ported to Kivy or Unity which can be ported to other systems...otherwise this can serve as a good lesson for learning how to script or create games as this is my first time in learning & using Python, using Blender and creating a Game.

Answer (score 2):

The BGE runs on

- Windows,
- MacOS,
- Linux.

Nintendo, PS2, Mobile phones do not run that platforms. So you can't use the BGE there even if there is a matching OpenGL support. (OpenGL is another requirement, not the only requirement)

> I want to create a game that can possibly be ported to Kivy or Unity which can be ported to other systems

I'm not sure how you interpret [porting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) a game to another platform or to use different frameworks. You basically develop a completely new application that feels like the original one. So the "business" stays the same while the application is completely different.

It is nothing ...

> for learning how to script or create games

If the question in your mind is meant to be:

- can I create BGE games on my mobile phone? the answer is no.
- can I run my BGE game in my mobile phone? The answer is no.
- can I transfer my BGE skills to other game engines that run on mobile phones? The answer is ... some of them:

  - concepts of game development.
  - scripting?

    - general concepts - yes
    - specific code - no
    - specific methods - not likely

[Edit]

> Can I create an OpenGL 1.1 game on Blender 2.78 32-bit Game Engine?

I can't tell. Accoring to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/451/what-version-of-opengl-does-blender-use) Blender 2.77+ needs OpenGL 2.1. I have no idea if that is compatible with OpenGL 1.1.

The supported OSes remain the same as mentioned above (WinOs, MacOs, Linux).

You might try it out by setting up a Linux with OpenGL 1.1 only.

Comment: The question I asked wasn't answered and the question I didn't ask was answered. I already knew that Blender wasn't for mobile, but I know people move their projects from 1 Engine to another...but I at the same time I know that emulators on PC and Mobile gauge how much a Game requires (My gauge for GPU is based on Sony's Console = PS1/PSP, PS2 & PS3/PS4) the reason why I want to create games that require less is for Low-End (2005) PCs which are approx equal to Mid-End (2012) Mobiles, so when it comes time to move it, there shouldn't be too many problems.

Comment: I know there are other things required, but if you think of Nintendo 3DS (OpenGL ES 1.1) graphics vs PS2 Emulator for Android (OpenGL ES 3.0) graphics??? Porting isn't easy, but Rockstar did put GTA:SA from PS2 > PC > Xbox 360 > Mobile, I'm pretty sure Rockstar's RAGE didn't support Android when they came with it on PS2. Also Android version supports CLEO, for modding GTA:SA like on PC.

Comment: Also for porting Panda3D uses C++ & Python so maybe it can be the bridge to Unity. Last thing...I know this is jumping the gun (Big Dreams, Bigger Picture), but if I make a lot, I want to put support into Blender, Kivy, Python, Cython, OpenGL, GLES & Valkuan (maybe PyOpenGL & Panda3D too) to create a Cross Platform Game/App Engine for End-Users that use Python (or C/C++/Cython/etc) and has the Tutorials made by BornCG with my Interface Design (I'm not going to explain it cause you'll misinterpret it). Most of those groups aren't greedy corporations & don't make any money.

Comment: Last thing, when I mentioned that Kivy is having trouble with Android/Mobile, I knew it made it equal to Blender's support and I only know Unity for everything else. I know your trying to help, I think I said to much, but I just wanted to know how someone can scale down the OpenGL requirements...also I heard Python is slow so Game = Slow...therefore use less = Better Speed?

Comment: I have no idea if you can run the bge on a pure OpenGl ES 1.1 platform. As far as I know Open GL is available on all supported OS platforms as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Currently I'm not sure what you want to do. Are going to develop a cross-platform game engine or a single game (e.g. for a mobile device).

Comment: Be aware even when the performance of a current mobile device is comparable with the performance of a 10 year old desktop, it makes them not compatible. I know many of us which we could run anything on everything just by doing so. But my car does not want to drive on railroad tracks, without a lot of effort.

Comment: approach ketsji game engine is on github, with jacob merril, as good and reliable as monster

Comment: THANKS MONSTER, I THINK have advice from you that helps on BGE, Sorry for sounding rude...APPARENTLY THE ANSWER IS ALL OVER THE PLACE...To Launch on Android & Control the Actor

Answer (score 0):

The reason I asked this question was to make **BGE Games for Android**, but upon hearing about **Blenderplayer** & testing it, they all failed [Blender 2.78-79]. Now I have found collective info on how to exactly do it because 1 human mentioned the Blender Version to use [**2.63 x64**].

BUT ALL MY ATTEMPTS COME UP EMPTY. Android 7 Arm64 w/4GB RAM, 32GB ROM, & GPU Adreno 500series w/OpenGLES 3.1.

1. LAUNCH BGE GAME ON ANDROID

- https://download.blender.org/demo/android/ [Blender.apk 08.19.12 == Flickering or Blenderplayer.apk 08.02.12.4 == No Start]
- Blender 2.63 [I'm using Non-Alpha/Beta Windows x64] https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.63/
- Credits Yorraki [Only person to mention BGE 2.63 needed] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnMRSYCB2Us

2. MAKE TOUCH KEYS

- Credits Quacksilber [Quick Tutor on how Move Object with Button Click] [How to move assets with a button click in BGE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130719/how-to-move-assets-with-a-button-click-in-bge)
- Credits BornCG [Simple Tutor Series, Clickable Button Video] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnEzrQqeP50

3. Credits BGE BELIEVERS

- On using Hover Over vs Left Click cause Touch detects 1st Tap as Hover
- Auto Start Game to avoid having to use Start Game thru Blender UI

NONE OF THIS WORKED SO FAR

Other things left out per Other Attempts

- Install Python3ForAndroid_r6.apk [https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/python-for-android/Python3ForAndroid_r6.apk]

PROBLEM IS TO DISABLE IN EDITOR.pc or PLAYER.android

- Disable Use System Framerate == Blender > Properties Editor > Render Tab > System Header > Use Frame Rate
- Use GLSL == Blender > Properties Editor > Render Tab > Shading > GLSL
- Use only Lights & Shaders == Blender > Properties Editor > Render Tab > Shading > GLSL > Uncheck Shadows, Color Management, Ramps, Nodes, Extra Textures
- Overlap Install Blenderplayer 08.02.12.4 then Blender 08.19.12 or reverse
- "Use simple Materials"