# How to move assets with a button click in BGE

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I just strated using blender game engine. I m making a game in which a ball or sphere move but i want to move it by the button on the screen. Which i made in another scene by overlay with main game screen. Can any one give me idea how do it. If i press the button with mouse ball should move in any dirction.

Answer (score 3):

Possible example: This will move the ball in one direction, if you press the button.
Welcome to the Blender StackExchange!

[image]

To detect the click on your button add a <kbd>mouse over</kbd> sensor and a <kbd>left button</kbd> sensor to your button. Combine them with the default AND controller and use a <kbd>message</kbd> actuator to send a message e.g. "moving" to your ball.
Make sure that one of the Sensors has **true-level-triggering** enabled, so your ball keeps moving while you keep pressing.

[image]

Catch that message to your ball with a <kbd>message</kbd> sensor (set right subject) and connect it with the motion you want.
[image]